# To get selected id of the dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the below code i have a dropdown in which i want to get the selected id of the product dropdown .Pls help me to do this.

To get id of product:

```
 function MyFunction() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "OrderForm.aspx/InsertData",
            data: "{'ProductID':'" + $("#<%=ProductName.ClientID%>").val() + "','Quantity':'" + $("#<%=txtQuantity.ClientID%>").val() + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: "true",
            cache: "false",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert("Success");
                // On success                 
            },
            Error: function (x, e) {
                alert("Fail");
                // On Error
            }
        });

    }
```

```html
<editable:EditableDropDownList ID="ProductName" runat= "server"  CssClass="cbProductName" style="width:40%;" EnableViewState="true"   />
```

Comment: `Error` should be `error`.

Comment: Why not `$("#ProductName").val()` ?

Comment: it's a value from view file. So this code is implemented in the view and like php variables can be parsed to the javascript

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at your `editable:EditableDropDownList`.
Because your select needs the value="this.id" in the loop.
I don't know which framework or plugins you are using, but search in the documentation for options to select the value of the options in the select.
If you dont define a value the select will send the displayed name as default value for the option.

```
<option value="1">Soap</option>
```

will send "1"

```
<option>Other</option>
```

will send "Other"

Comment: I am getting the value not id

Comment: which id do you need? the element id? or an attribute? tell me and i can show you the code

Comment: in my sql Server tbl i have productID and ProductName ie 1  Soap ,  2  oats .if i select soap i want to get id 1